# loadCibName: Difficulties

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I load a xib doing this:

```
[contentViews addObject:[[HMUISettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:"SettingsView" bundle:nil]];
```

In SettingsView.xib file owner is HMUISettingsViewController. One outlet of HMUISettingsViewController is calendarTableView, but the problem is: it's always non-existent if I try to access it. This is an excerpt of the HMUISettingsViewController class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{   
    // Set delegate for resizing
    [mainSplitView setDelegate:self];
}

- (void)splitView:(NSSplitView)sender resizeSubviewsWithOldSize:(NSSize)oldSize
{
    var calendarTableFrame = [calendarTableView frame]; // Doesn't work!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you bound your outlet to an actual calendar table view in the xib file?

Comment: What do you mean by "non-existent"? Is it nil or is it just not visible on the screen?

Comment: Do you have other outlets? If yes, are they nils as well? Post some more code, especially the contentViews array.

Comment: Hm. I don't know why, but now it works. I double checked everything and could't find any mistake (there are even not many mistakes to make because the class has only two outlets…). So I thought maybe there is something internally messed up (Xcode just crashed), and I created a new xib from scratch. That solved the problem. Anyways, thanks for your support!